# How to hide remove next and previous buttons in standard pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I need  numbered only pagination on a wordpress page.
I tried to remove the "next" and the "previous" buttons, just to leave the numbered boxes for pagination but this did not work.
I found this tutorial here and http://www.egtutorial.com/howto/how-to-add-numeric-or-numbered-pagination-in-wordpress/
but no way to remove this button. Here the main part of the php code, but if somebody knows a css solution, its welcome, too, but css code .next { display: none }
did not work... thanks in advance for ideas.

'page/%#%',
            'current' => $paged,
            'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages,
            'mid_size'  => 4,
            'prev_text'       => __('« Prev Page'),
            'next_text'       => __('Next Page »')
        ) );
        ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the arguments the following variable.

```
'prev_next' => false
```

`prev_text` and `next_text` are displayed only if `prev_next` is true. For more information check the [`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function.